# How to return array from database in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I want to return my result as array list. My code looks like this:

```
public Person Get(string doctorCode)
{
     using (PharmaOCEAN_LTEntities entities = new PharmaOCEAN_LTEntities())                   
     {
         return entities.Person.FirstOrDefault(e => e.DoctorLicenseNumber == doctorCode);
     }
}
```

Some guy informed me that selected (all) result will be an array, so I tried this way, but im getting an error with select statement:

```
public IList<Person> Get(string doctorCode)
{
    using (PharmaOCEAN_LTEntities entities = new PharmaOCEAN_LTEntities())                   
    {
        return entities.Person.Select<Person>(e => e.DoctorLicenseNumber == doctorCode);
    }
}
```

any opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah sure you can!
As a array:

```
public Person[] Get(string doctorCode)
{
    using (PharmaOCEAN_LTEntities entities = new PharmaOCEAN_LTEntities())                   
    {
        return entities.Person.Where(e => e.DoctorLicenseNumber == doctorCode).ToArray();
    }
}
```

As a list:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Get(string doctorCode)
{
    using (PharmaOCEAN_LTEntities entities = new PharmaOCEAN_LTEntities())                   
    {
        return entities.Person.Where(e => e.DoctorLicenseNumber == doctorCode).ToList();
    }
}
```

not sure if it compiles, but you get the message :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide info error that you get?

Don't you have to add `ToList()` at the end of select statement?